# Google Analytics - site with 2 domains, how to track each domain individually?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website with 2 domains.  I am trying to track the domains separately.  I have both domains inside the same GA account - each domain has a filter applied to it to exclude the other's domain (both with and without the www).  It looks like the domains are still being tracked together.  How would I go about separating these 2 for different results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing now is sending all the traffic to one account (say, UA-XXXX-1), and then using filters to separate them out. This is an imperfect solution, since filters have odd session-related quirks that make them less than ideal for tracking completely separate domains.

To *completely* separate the results, you need to create separate new web properties within your Google Analytics accounts , so that instead of tracking the second domain on UA-XXXX-1 and filtering, to send the data to UA-XXXX-2. It will roll up in the same area of your analytics account, but it will totally separate and segment the data.

[You can read more about the organizational concepts here at this excellent Google Analytics Help Center walkthrough.](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts.html)

To set this up, you'll setup a new profile within the account and select "Add a profile for a new domain" as your option. [There's a detailed walk through here.](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55486)